# Multiple versions of library inside a library

Tags: android, dependencies

So I have one Library A which is used in my app and Library B which is also used in my app.
Library B internally uses a different version of Library A.
So my app has LibA - v1 and LibB has LibA- v2.

when I run my app, Lib B also starts using v1.
How do I make sure that LibB uses v2 everytime?

Answer (score 1):

You cannot have more than one version of the same classes in the same app.

Your options include:

1. Update your app to use the v2 version of the library too.
2. Fork the library and change its package names so you can have two different versions of it in the app.